# phpMyAdminのデータベーステーブルからデータをCSVファイルで出力したいがエラーになる

Tags: phpmyadmin

#### 行った操作手順

1．出力したテーブルを選択し、エクスポートを選択。
　2．フォーマット：　　　　　　　　　SQL➡CSVに変更
　3．出力：の中のフィルの文字セット　utf-8➡SHIFT＿JISに変更
　4．エンコーディングへの変換：　　　なし➡SJISへ変更
　5．実行ボタンをクリック

上記の操作を行いましたが、下記にあるよう「失敗－ネットワークエラー」と表示されてしまいます。
➡CSVファイルに出力し、Excelでデータを編集したいと考えています。

#### 動作環境

OS：Windows
PHP：8.1.4
phpMyAdmin：5.1.3

ご教示お願い致します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: phpMyAdmin 5.1.3 はPHP 8.1で不具合があるようです。　https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71615310/failed-network-error-when-i-exporting-from-phpmyadmin

Comment: ありがとうございます